# Floating and clearing in columns

Tags: css

I have a list of items that needs to be floated into columns. **Item 1 and 2 to the left**, and **three and four to the right**. Each item has a width of 49%.

Using this css makes item three and four float to the right, but not all the way up:

```css
.one,
.two {
  float: left;
}

.two {
  clear: both;
}

.three,
.four {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="one">1</div>
  <div class="two">2</div>
  <div class="three">3</div>
  <div class="four">4</div>
</div>
```

Why is that and how can it be fixed?
[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lhjya4p2/1/).

Note: I can't use a `flexbox` or `column-count` solution due to dynamic content, menaning that sometimes there should be one item to the left and three to the right, or the opposite.

Comment: Please post the screenshot of the final layout

Comment: by dynamic content, do you mean the number of child divs or the content inside the 4 divs?

Comment: I think Flexbox is the solution here, if not, you might have to do something ugly like setting heights to the elements and adding negative margins to them.

Comment: By dynamic content, I mean that sometimes there should be one item to the left and three to the right, or the opposite.

Answer (score 2):

In short: No.

In less short: No, Float does not support what you want.

Source: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float)

> left The element must float on the left side of its containing block.
>
> right The element must float on the right side of its containing
> block.

The way this works is as follows (taking your example)

- Div 1 floats to the left.
- Div 2 floats to the left, under div 1.
- Div 3 float to the right, under div 2.
- Div 4 floats right, under div 3.

Floats don't ignore each other (within a parent), only the rest of the DOM (within that parent).

Without the use of `grid` or `flex`, I don't see your request becoming a reality.

I suggest using `flex` on your parent div, and maybe use a set of `:nth-child` selectors and `order` properties to get the right base to apply your layout to.

Taking in account your recent comment:

> By dynamic content, I mean that sometimes there should be one item to the left and three to the right, or the opposite.

This should be either determined server-side by including a CSS class to the parent div or, use client-side code to count the amount of div's in that parent, and determine how to display those. In combination with a CSS class you can do any layout you want.

But again, in short: No, not possible using just `float`s.

Comment: Thank you very much for a clear answer. I will work out another solution.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you mean by dynamic content, but if it's only the content inside the 4 divs then couldn't you use flex like so:

```css
.box {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.content {
  width: 49%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid red
}

.one {
  order: 1;
}

.two {
  order: 3;
}

.three {
  order: 2;
}

.four {
  order: 4;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="content one">1</div>
  <div class="content two">2</div>
  <div class="content three">3</div>
  <div class="content four">4</div>
</div>
```

If your dynamic content is the number of boxes, then you would most likely have to use a server side or js solution to change the html structure

**Update**

Per your comment that the dynamic content means the placement of the divs, then you would need a server side or js solution for that as css won't be able to change the placement of your boxes based on content - unless you are just wanting even height columns based on the content of your divs, in which case, use [css columns](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/columns)

Comment: he stated: Note: I can't use a flexbox or column-count solution due to dynamic content.

Comment: @curveball - as stated in my answer - if the dynamic content is only the content inside the divs, then OP can use flex

Comment: By dynamic content, I mean that sometimes there should be one item to the left and three to the right, or the opposite.

Comment: @Meek Then you would need a server side / js solution that included the logic for where the items should go - there is no css that can swap the order of things randomly like that (also that completely changes your question - ie 1 and 2 to the left 3 and 4 to the right)

Answer (score 0):

Is this the pattern you are looking for ?

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.box-col{
  float: left;
}

.box div {
  width: 49%;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

body *,
body *:before,
body *:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}
```

```html
<h3>How can these two columns be aliged?</h3>
<div class="box row">
  <div class="one box-col">1</div>
  <div class="two box-col">2</div>
  <div class="three box-col">3</div>
  <div class="four box-col">4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's not what they're asking for, it should be 1 and 2 on the left and 3 and 4 on the right.

Comment: Please don't use `float`, it's obsolete.